# $X_1, X_2,...$ be i.i.d. with characteristic funciton $\phi(t) = e^{-|t|^\alpha}$, $\alpha < 1$. Show that the weak law of large numbers does not hold

Tags: probability

Let $X_1, X_2,...$ be i.i.d. with characteristic funciton $\phi(t) = e^{-|t|^\alpha}$, where $0 < \alpha < 2$. Suppose $\alpha < 1$. Show that the weak law of large numbers does not hold, that is, there is no constant $\mu$ such that $\frac{X_1+\cdots + X_n}{n} \to \mu$ in probability.

If it is of any use, I have already showed that $\frac{X_1+\cdots + X_n}{n^\frac{1}{\alpha}}$ has the same distribution as $X_1$, and $var(X_1) = \infty$. But I'm still unsure how to approach this problem.

Comment: The sample mean $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ seems to have characteristic function $(\phi(t/n))^n = e^{-|t|^\alpha n^{1-\alpha}}$ so it isn't exactly the same distribution as $X_1$.

Comment: @angryavian It was a typo; thanks for the catch.

Comment: *Hint.* So you get that $\left\lvert\frac{X_1+\cdots+X_n}n\right\rvert\stackrel d=n^{\frac1\alpha-1}\lvert X_1\rvert$. The right-hand side converges to $\infty$ as soon as $X_1\neq0$. Can then the left-hand side converge to a real number?

Comment: The law of large numbers always hold, as far as I remember. That is to say, if $EX = \mu$ finite, then $\bar X_n \to \mu$ a.s.; if $EX = \infty,$ then $\lim \bar X_n = \infty$ a.s. as well. Therefore, they want a weaker result than this (i.e. the assumuption that the variates are infinitely divisible is not needed). You can consider a truncated variable $X^t = \min(X, t),$ then $\bar X_n^t \to E(X^t)$ a.s., and by letting $t \to \infty,$ you see that $\bar X_n \geq \bar X_n^t \xrightarrow{n\to \infty} E(X^t) \xrightarrow{t\to \infty} \infty.$

Comment: Now, I just realised that your variables are symmetric, so my previous comment does not apply (here you have $EX^+ = EX^- = \infty$, so $EX$ does not exists). I leave it since it is still interesting. The SLLN for this case still exists but it now states that $\limsup \bar X_n = \infty$ and $\liminf \bar X_n = -\infty,$ a.s. (Of course, this finishes the exercise since convergence in probability implies convergence a.s. through a subsequence, but to show the SLLN in this case is harder than a truncation.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@nejimban already provided a solution based on the actual hypothesis of the exercise. Here is another one in which the infinitely divisible assumption is dropped.

**Theorem (Theorem 4 of Feller's *An Introduction to probability Theory and Its Applications*, vol 2, sect. VII.9, p. 241).** Let $(X_n)_n$ be a sequence if independent variates with a common law satisfying $\mathbf{E}(|X_1|) = \infty.$ For whatever the constant $c_n$ may be,
$$
\limsup |n^{-1} S_n - c_n| = \infty,
$$
with probability one, where $S_n = X_1 + \ldots + X_n.$

*Sketch of proof.* Let $A_k(m) = \{|X_k| > mk\}.$ Then, the events $A_k(m)$ are independent and $\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty \mathbf{P}(A_k(m)) = \infty,$ the Borel-Cantelli lemma implies that infinitely many of them occur almost surely. Therefore, the event $L(m) = \left\{\limsup\limits_{k \to \infty} \dfrac{|X_k|}{k} \geq m \right\}$ has probability one, and so $\bigcap\limits_{m = 1}^\infty L(m)$ also has probability one. As a consequence, $\dfrac{|X_k|}{k}$ is an unbounded sequence a.s. Since $X_k = S_k - S_{k-1},$ the boundedness of $\dfrac{|S_n|}{n}$ would entail that of $\dfrac{|X_k|}{k}$ and so $\dfrac{|S_n|}{n}$ is unbounded, proving the claim for $c_n = 0.$ The proof of the general case follows by a "symmetrisation" argument, meaning we consider $Y_k = X_k - X_k',$ where $(X_n')_n$ is an independent copy of the whole sequence $(X_n).$ It can be shown that the $Y_k$ are independent, identically distributed with $\mathbf{E}(|Y_1|) = \infty.$ *A fortiori*, $\dfrac{|S_n^Y|}{n}$ is unbounded (with obvious choice of notation), and $S_n^Y$ is a symmetrisation of $S_n - n c_n,$ and the boundedness of $\dfrac{|S_n - n c_n|}{n}$ would entail that of $\dfrac{|S_n^Y|}{n},$ which then implies that $\dfrac{|S_n-nc_n|}{n} = |n^{-1}S_n - c_n|$ is unbounded, as desired. CQFD

Comment: [+1] It should be $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\color{red}{\mathbb P\bigl(}A_k(m)\color{red}{\bigr)}=\infty$ there.

Comment: @nejimban thanks